# how to power up a subtractor using a window comparator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, comparator

I'm making a circuit that will detect whether a voltage(V1)is in between the range 1-2 V. If so I want to switch ON a subtractor and output V1 - 1 V.

I initially thought of connecting the output of the **window comparator** to power up the subtractor. What i thought was if V1 is in the correct range, the window comparator's output will be around +7V so I connected it to the supply of the subtractor(created using an opamp).

However what i noticed is that the output voltage drops significantly when powering up the subtractor. Is there any better recommended way which I can use?

[image: subtractor]

[image: window comparator]

Comment: "Powering up" parts of your circuit is almost certainly not the right way to go about it. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is the output supposed to be when the input voltage is not within the window?

Comment: Actually I'm making a circuit which can detect voltage ranges 0-1V, 1-2V, 2-3V, 3-4V, 4-5V and I'm going to amplify that 1Volt difference to 0-5Volts.. that's why I thought of use window comparator stages and then subtract each offset so that i can finally get a voltage which is between 0-1V which is then amplified to 0-5V

Comment: That is why I thought of using the window comparator as the 'if' clause.. my approach may seem bit inefficient

Comment: What is the output used for? Is there just a single output or five separate outputs? This really sounds like an X-Y problem that could be addressed much more cleanly some other way.

Comment: Let's say I give 3.055V, I want to get **3V** and 0.055*5= **0.275V** .. these are the two values I'm going to feed to the micro-controller analog pins.. (I'm building an ambient light sensing device... I'm doing all these stuff to increase the resolution of the calculated illuminance value - micro-controller can accept only 0-5Volts)

Comment: I suspected as much. If you need better ADC resolution, it is easier to simply add an external ADC with the required resolution than to create this Rube Goldberg analog circuit to try to make the internal one work. For example, we had a recent question about [this low-speed SPI ADC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/429949/11683).

Comment: A better external ADC is much better than 5 gain circuits.  The gain and offset of each gain circuit will have to be calibrated within the microcontroller.  And with the gain and offset errors you may even have gaps where the gain circuits show no change for a small increase in input, because one gain circuit maxes out early and the next one starts late.

Comment: Far better to use a Panasonic logarithmic CIE corrected Light Sensor in a 5mm case . Cheaper and better in that it spans > 4 decades and may be scaled by output R . Only needs an LDO and output R